# Recover or Reset root Password

Tags: mysql

New mysql install  while login or  setup  new mysql  password using

mysqladmin -u root password "NEWPASSWORD"
getting
error:

> mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Also  i   tried to  use -h option with my server hostname still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

Step # 1: Stop the MySQL service.

```
            # /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

Step # 2: Start the MySQL with the --skip-grant-tables option (it will allow you to login without mysql password)

```
            # mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Step # 3: Connect to mysql server as the root user.

```
            # mysql -u root
```

Step # 4: Now Setup new mysql root User password.

```
            mysql> use mysql;
            mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD")
                     where User='root';
            mysql> flush privileges;
            mysql> quit
```

Step # 5: Exit and restart the MySQL server.

```
           # /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

step # 6: login and test new mysql password

```
           # mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: You should use --skip-networking too. And perhaps make sure no one can log in via ssh.

Comment: thanks chris for sharing additional  information.

Comment: The comment placeholder says _Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”_... I try to say thanks with an upvote. Moderating helps helpful stuff to float to the top. (And welcome to Stack Overflow, BTW)